# How to modify the Lua If Statement?

Tags: if-statement, lua

I was trying to use the Lua if function to represent the result with a “*” in front of the value under a circumstance using an if function.

```
fefec    C2 
--------------
 2       *2        
 3        3
```

When the value in Column 1 (fefec) is smaller than 3, then it is shown as * with the value entered in C2. When the value in C1 is equal or greater than 3, it is shown the actual value in C2. The code I wrote is

```
(function()
   if [f#fefec] < 3 then
     return "*[f#fefec]"
   else return [f#fefec]
   end
 end)()
```

But for the first row, I got *(2.000000000000), how can I get rid of these 0s after 2?

Comment: Please add content to the actual question instead of linking to a screenshot. This way if the screenshot goes away or the image sharing site is down, the question still makes sense.

Comment: Please read your question again. So far the answer is either "YES" or "NO". So I guess you should improve your question so it will yield something useful. I'd also recommend that you provide some own code. What you expect it to do and what it does instead. Then many people will love to help you to fix that issue. Please read [ask] befor you continue.

Comment: A good start could be `if(c1<3) then ...else ... end`

Comment: Hi, the code I used is (function() if C1 <3 then return "*[f#C1]" else return [f#C1] end end)() but it shows *(2.000000000000), is there anyway to get rid of the 0s after 2?

Comment: What is the [f#fefec] part even supposed to do? I've never seen such thing in Lua. Is this some modified environment / spreadsheet application?

Comment: To get correct format of numbers use `string.format("%d", 2.00000000000)` You get `2` instead of `2.000000000000`. Read more about it in [Tutorial: Formatting values using “string.format()”](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2015/02/17/tutorial-formatting-values-using-string-format/).